# The closure's properties on metric space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that

1) $
{A}\mathrm{\subset}\overline{A}
$

2) $
\overline{\mathop{A}\limits^{\mathrm{{-}}}}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{A}\limits^{\mathrm{{-}}}
$

3) $
\overline{{A}\mathrm{\cup}{B}\hspace{0.33em}}\mathrm{{=}}\overline{A}\mathrm{\cup}\mathop{B}\limits^{\mathrm{{-}}}
$

4) $
\overline{{A}\mathrm{\cup}{B}\hspace{0.33em}}\mathrm{\subset}\overline{A}\mathrm{\cap}\overline{B}
$

İ will show my attempt for the fourth and third part.

$
\begin{array}{l}
{{x}\mathrm{\in}\overline{{A}\mathrm{\cup}{B}}\mathrm{\Rightarrow}{B}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cap}{\mathrm{(}}{A}\mathrm{\cup}{B}{\mathrm{)}}\rlap{/}{\mathrm{{=}}}\mathit{\Phi}}\\
{\mathrm{\Rightarrow}{\mathrm{((}}{B}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cap}{A}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cup}{\mathrm{(}}{B}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cap}{B}{\mathrm{))}}\rlap{/}{\mathrm{{=}}}\mathit{\Phi}}\\
{\mathrm{\Rightarrow}{\mathrm{(}}{B}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cap}{A}{\mathrm{)}}\rlap{/}{\mathrm{{=}}}\mathit{\Phi}\hspace{0.33em}{or}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{(}}{B}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\cap}{B}{\mathrm{)}}\rlap{/}{\mathrm{{=}}}\mathit{\Phi}}\\
{\mathrm{\Rightarrow}{x}\mathrm{\in}\mathop{A}\limits^{\mathrm{{-}}}\mathrm{\cup}\mathop{B}\limits^{\mathrm{{-}}}}
\end{array}
$

We can derive the reverse implications in same way.

Do you have there any ideas for the first and second part? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt at 3) is incorrect . The 4th line does not follow immediately from the 3rd.

In general $\forall r>0 \;(S(r)\lor T(r))$ does not imply $(\forall r>0 \;(S(r))\lor (\forall r>0 \;(T(r)).$ (For example if $S(r)$ is $r\in \mathbb N$ and $T(r)$ is $r\not \in \mathbb N)$.

In your attempt, $S(r)$ is $B_r(x)\cap A\ne \phi$  and $T(r)$ is $B_r(x)\cap B\ne \phi$.

$\bar A$ and $\bar B$ are (obviously) subsets of $\overline {A\cup B}$ so $\bar A \cup \bar B\subset \overline {A\cup B}.$ So to prove 3) is  suffices to prove $$\bullet \quad \overline {A\cup B}\subset \bar A\cup \bar B.$$  Now $\bullet$ is equivalent to $$\forall x (\;(x\not \in\bar A\land x\not \in\bar B)\implies x\not \in \overline {A\cup B}\;\;).$$

If $x\not\in \bar A$ and $x\not \in \bar B$ then there exist $r>0$ and $s>0$ such that $A\cap B_r(x)=\phi=B\cap B_s(x).$ So let $t=\min (r,s).$ Then  $t>0$ and  $$B_t(x)\cap (A\cup B)=$$ $$=(B_t(x)\cap A)\;\cup\; (B_t(x)\cap B)\subset$$ $$\subset (B_r(x)\cap A)\;\cup \;(B_s(x)\cap B)=$$ $$=\phi \cup \phi =\phi$$ implying  $x\not \in \overline {A\cup B} $.

Remarks. As of 11 p.m. EST March 11, number 4) reads $\overline {A\cup B}\subset \bar A \cap \bar B,$ which is false,e.g. $A=\mathbb R^+$ and $B=\mathbb R^-$..... It is more common to write $B(x,r)$ rather than $B_r(x).$

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean for a point $x$ to be in $\bar{A}$? By definition, it means that every ball $B_r(x)$ around $x$ contains a point in $A$.

So if $x \in A$, does it follow that $x \in \bar{A}$? Well, given a ball $B_r(x)$ around $x$, does this ball contain a point in $A$? Yes! $x$ itself is a point in $A$ and is contained in $B_r(x)$. So $A \subset \bar{A}$.

Next, if $x \in \bar{\bar{A}}$, does it follow that $x \in \bar{A}$? Given a ball $B_r(x)$ around $x$, we know that this ball contains a point $y \in \bar{A}$, by the definition of $\bar{\bar{A}}$. But since $y \in \bar{A}$, any ball around $y$ must contain a point in $A$. Applying this observation to a ball $B_{r'}(y)$ chosen small enough that $B_{r'}(y) \subset B_r(x)$, we see that $B_{r'}(y)$ contains a point $z \in A$. But then, $z \in B_r(x)$. So we have succeeding in showing that for every $x \in \bar{\bar{A}}$ and every ball $B_r(x)$ around $x$, there exists a point $z \in A$ contained in $B_r(x)$, i.e. we have succeeded in showing that $\bar{\bar{A}} \subset \bar{A}$.

I hope you get the idea.